# Identify mobile device platform (Android or iOS) in MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

Is there a way to determine what platform is sending an SMS message? The goal is to provide a dynamic link to the AppStore or Google Play to download an App depending on the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this information from MobilePushDemographics if you have it.

If not, you can redirect to a specific web page which checks the plattform of the device(using javascript), and then redirect accordingly.

Comment: We were trying to avoid having to code a Cloud Page, but I thought this was going to be the case. Thanks.